# Why is this statement about expectation value true?

Tags: probability, expected-value

I have the following statement about expectation value in stochastics.

> $Var(X)=\Bbb{E}((x-\Bbb{E}(X))^2)$

We had the definition that $Var(X)=\Bbb{E}(X^2)-(\Bbb{E}(X))^2$. So the prove is really short and everything is clear except one point.

I would prove this as follows:

> $\Bbb{E}((x-\Bbb{E}(X))^2)=\Bbb{E}(X^2-2X\Bbb{E}(X)+\Bbb{E}(X)^2)$ now using linearity we get $\Bbb{E}(X^2)-2\Bbb{E}(X)\Bbb{E}(X)+\Bbb{E}(X)^2=\Bbb{E}(X^2)-\Bbb{E}(X)^2$.

Now the point I don't get is why is $\Bbb{E}(\Bbb{E}(X))=\Bbb{E}(X)$? Could someone please help me there?

Thanks a lot

Comment: $E[a]=a$ for constant $a$. Let $a=E[X]$.

Comment: Not that it makes much difference, but $Var(X)=\Bbb{E}((X-\Bbb{E}(X))^2)$ is a more logical definition as it is the second moment about the mean and then you show it is also $\Bbb{E}(X^2)-(\Bbb{E}(X))^2$

Comment: but do I fix a value $\omega \in \Omega$ and then compute $\Bbb{E}(X(\omega))$ if $X:\Omega\rightarrow M$? and therefore $\Bbb{E}(X)$ is always a constant but depending on $\omega$?

Comment: @Wave  $E[E[X]]=\int_{\Omega}E[X]dP=\int_{\Omega}\int_{\Omega}XdPdP=\int_{\Omega}XdP\int_{\Omega}dP=\int_{\Omega}XdP=E[X]$

Comment: @Golden_Ratio but is it correct that we need to apply this for all $\omega\in \Omega$? And could one also use the definitoon $\Bbb{E}(X)=\sum_\Omega X(\omega)p(\omega)$? Because we did't have the one with integrals

Comment: @Wave The expected value integrates out over $\omega\in \Omega$

Comment: @Golden_Ratio I changed my last comment maybe you could take a look at it again

Comment: What do you mean "apply this for all $\omega$"? Even if $X$ is a function of $\omega$,  the expected value integrates out $\omega$. And the Lebesgue integral includes the discrete case

Comment: @Golden_Ratio sorry yes I saw that this point do not makes sense. but for your proof using the integral could you maybe help me using my definition on sums?

Comment: @Wave A sum is also an integral. It's the same idea. You are simply pulling a constant (that just happens to be an expected value) out of a sum.

Comment: so but in the sum where do I need to put my $\Bbb{E}(X)$? and where do I need to put the $\omega$ after $X(\omega)$ in the sum so I really don't see how to get the same solution as in your way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134693/discussion-between-golden-ratio-and-wave).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

${\cal E}[x]$ is a constant (for any specified distribution over $x$).... and of course the expected value of a constant is that constant.

Comment: but isn't $X$ a function (named the random variable) or do we look at $\Bbb{E}(X(\omega))$ if $X:\Omega\rightarrow M$ in any set $M$?

Comment: X is a function with expected value E(X). Let’s assume the function has mean 5 and so E(X)=5. Then E(E(X))=E(5)=5. Therefore, E(E(x))=E(X) in general because E(X) is just a number @Wave

Comment: @FD_bfa:  Ummm... isn't that precisely what is stated in the accepted answer?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Yes, Wave’s comment seemed to indicate that they were still a bit unsure and so I just added to your answer with a concrete example.